# fetch request shows undefined when trying to access an array within an array (svelte)

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, svelte, sveltekit

I'm having trouble understanding what I'm missing when trying to access this data from an API the data I'm trying to access is an array within an array but when I try to access it, it will either show me `[object, object]` or `undefined`.

the svelte store

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

export const leagueStandings = writable([]);

const fetchStandings= async () => { 
  const url = 'https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/standings/season/17420?api_token=API_KEY';
  const res = await fetch(url); 
  const data = await res.json();
  leagueStandings.set(data.data);
} 
fetchStandings();
```

the svelte component

```
<script>
import {leagueStandings} from "../../stores/league-standings-stores"
console.log(leagueStandings)

let tablePositions = leagueStandings.map($leagueStandings => $leagueStandings.standings)

console.log(tablePositions)

</script>
```

```html
{#each tablePositions as tablePosition}
  <h2>{tablePosition.position}</h2>
{/each}
```

The API with, im trying to get my data from "standings". i can the content to show in a console.log() but cant actually access the values :(

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 77448322,
            "name": "Regular Season",
            "league_id": 8,
            "season_id": 17420,
            "round_id": 202038,
            "round_name": 38,
            "type": "Group Stage",
            "stage_id": 77448322,
            "stage_name": "Regular Season",
            "resource": "stage",
            "standings": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "position": 1,
                        "team_id": 9,
                        "team_name": "Manchester City",
                        "round_id": 202038,
                        "round_name": 38,
                        "group_id": null,
                        "group_name": null,
                        "overall": {
                            "games_played": 38,
                            "won": 27,
                            "draw": 5,
                            "lost": 6,
                            "goals_scored": 83,
                            "goals_against": 32,
                            "points": 86
                        },
                        "home": {
                            "games_played": 19,
                            "won": 13,
                            "draw": 2,
                            "lost": 4,
                            "goals_scored": 43,
                            "goals_against": 17,
                            "points": 41
                        },
                        "away": {
                            "games_played": 19,
                            "won": 14,
                            "draw": 3,
                            "lost": 2,
                            "goals_scored": 40,
                            "goals_against": 15,
                            "points": 45
                        },
                        "total": {
                            "goal_difference": "51",
                            "points": 86
                        },
                        "result": "UEFA Champions League",
                        "points": 86,
                        "recent_form": "WLWLW",
                        "status": null
                    },
```

Comment: Is `url` meant to be a string? Right now, it's a syntax error

Comment: @Phil If `url` wasn't supposed to be a string, then OP would be getting a different error. I'll edit the mistake.

Comment: @MichaelM. I'd rather OP posted actual code. It makes it very hard to diagnose problems when you're not looking at the real thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standings property is an object with property `data` that is an array but you don't seem to be accounting for such a structure.

If you want to flatten all the `standings.data` arrays into a single list, try this...

```js
const tablePositions = leagueStandings.flatMap(
  ({ standings: { data } }) => data
);
```